# Closed set containing infinite arithmetic progressions of ANY gap

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, arithmetic-progression, hausdorff-dimension

Let $A\subseteq [0,\infty)$ be a set containing infinite arithmetic progressions of ANY gap, that is, for any $d>0$, there is $t>0$ such that $t+kd\in A$ for all $k\in \mathbb N$.

Molter and Yavicoli (2016) showed that there exists such set $A$ which is $F_\sigma$ and has zero Hausdorff dimension. Their set, however, is dense in some $[M,\infty)$ (in particular, it cannot be closed).

My question is: does there exist a CLOSED set of zero Hausdorff dimension with the above property?

I attempted to show that if $A$ contains infinite arithmetic progressions of any gap, then $A$ must be dense somewhere, so a closed $A$ contains an interval. However, I was wrong, as the following post gives me a counterexample:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2702705/a-nowhere-dense-set-containing-arbitrarily-close-arithmetic-progressions

Nevertheless, I can show that if $A\subseteq [0,\infty)$ contains a translated copy of any sequence $\alpha_i$ increasing to infinity, then $A$ must be dense in some $[M,\infty)$.